# reusing xna primitives via class

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Is there any way to make a primitive and use it over and over again? ex: if I make one cube, can I create 100 and make a 10x10 grid? I've tried using a for loop and updating the x and z coords with each loop thru, but it only moves the one cube thats created in the beginning. My class was created using an example from a book. I know how to move the cube around the area by changing the coords in the PositionCube method. What can I do in my main game class that will allow me to create a simple 10x10 grid?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Cube_Chaser
{
    class Cube
    {
        private GraphicsDevice device;
        private Texture2D texture;

        public Vector3 location;

        private Vector3 position;

        private VertexBuffer cubeVertexBuffer;
        private List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices = new List<VertexPositionTexture>();

        public Cube(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Vector3 playerLocation, float minDistance, Texture2D texture)
        {
            device = graphicsDevice;
            this.texture = texture;

            PositionCube(playerLocation, minDistance);

            BuildFace(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 1));
            BuildFace(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
            BuildFace(new Vector3(1, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
            BuildFace(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

            BuildFaceHorizontal(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
            BuildFaceHorizontal(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0));

            cubeVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionTexture.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Count, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

            cubeVertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionTexture>(vertices.ToArray());

            this.position = position;
        }

        private void BuildFace(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
        {
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 0));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p2.Y, p1.Z, 1, 1));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 0, 1));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 0, 1));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p1.Y, p2.Z, 0, 0));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 0));
        }

        private void BuildFaceHorizontal(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
        {
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 0, 1));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 1));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1, 0));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 0, 1));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1, 0));
            vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p2.Z, 0, 0));
        }

        private VertexPositionTexture BuildVertex(float x, float y, float z, float u, float v)
        {
            return new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(x, y, z), new Vector2(u, v));
        }

        public void PositionCube(Vector3 playerLocation, float minDistance)
        {
            location = new Vector3(.5f, .5f, .5f);
        }

        public void Draw(Camera camera, BasicEffect effect)
        {
            effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
            effect.TextureEnabled = true;
            effect.Texture = texture;

            Matrix center = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
            Matrix scale = Matrix.CreateScale(0.05f);
            Matrix translate = Matrix.CreateTranslation(location);

            effect.World = center * scale * translate;
            effect.View = camera.View;
            effect.Projection = camera.Projection;

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
                device.SetVertexBuffer(cubeVertexBuffer);
                device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, cubeVertexBuffer.VertexCount / 3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Reusing" implies that you use object which is _no longer needed_. In your case you modify cube which is _already in use_. Which is why you observe the described behaviour. If you need to display 100 cubes - by all means - create 100 cubes. There is not much to optimize in this scenario, when there is a fixed number of objects to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @nico-schetler 's answer and created the classes for you.

Cube.cs

```
class Cube
{
    private GraphicsDevice device;
    private VertexBuffer cubeVertexBuffer;

    public Cube(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        device = graphicsDevice;

        var vertices = new List<VertexPositionTexture>();

        BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 1));
        BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
        BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(1, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
        BuildFace(vertices, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

        BuildFaceHorizontal(vertices, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
        BuildFaceHorizontal(vertices, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(1, 0, 0));

        cubeVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionTexture.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Count, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

        cubeVertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionTexture>(vertices.ToArray());
    }

    private void BuildFace(List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
    {
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 0));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p2.Y, p1.Z, 1, 1));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 0, 1));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 0, 1));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p1.Y, p2.Z, 0, 0));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 0));
    }

    private void BuildFaceHorizontal(List<VertexPositionTexture> vertices, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
    {
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 0, 1));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1, 1));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1, 0));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 0, 1));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1, 0));
        vertices.Add(BuildVertex(p1.X, p1.Y, p2.Z, 0, 0));
    }

    private VertexPositionTexture BuildVertex(float x, float y, float z, float u, float v)
    {
        return new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(x, y, z), new Vector2(u, v));
    }

    public void Draw( BasicEffect effect)
    {
        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            device.SetVertexBuffer(cubeVertexBuffer);
            device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, cubeVertexBuffer.VertexCount / 3);
        }
    }
}
```

CubeDrawable.cs

```
public class DrawableList<T> : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private BasicEffect effect;
    private Camera camera;
    private class Entity
    {
        public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
        public Matrix Orientation { get; set; }
        public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    }

    private Cube cube;
    private List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>();

    public DrawableList (Game game, Camera camera, BasicEffect effect) 
        : base( game ) 
    {
        this.effect = effect;
        cube = new Cube (game.GraphicsDevice);
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    public void Add( Vector3 position, Matrix orientation, Texture2D texture )
    {
        entities.Add (new Entity() { 
            Position = position,
            Orientation = orientation,
            Texture = texture
        });
    }

    public override void Draw (GameTime gameTime )
    {
        base.Draw (gameTime);

        foreach (var item in entities) {

            effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
            effect.TextureEnabled = true;
            effect.Texture = item.Texture;

            Matrix center = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
            Matrix scale = Matrix.CreateScale(0.05f);
            Matrix translate = Matrix.CreateTranslation(item.Position);

            effect.World = center * scale * translate;
            effect.View = camera.View;
            effect.Projection = camera.Projection;

            cube.Draw (effect);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
        camera = new Camera (graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        effect = new BasicEffect (graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        cubes = new DrawableList<Cube> (this, camera, effect);

        Components.Add (cubes);

        for (int i=0 ; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cubes.Add (new Vector3( i*0.5f, 50.0f, 50.0f), Matrix.Identity, logoTexture);
        }
```

Comment: I used your classes and everything checks out, but when compiled I get an error "Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Cube_Chaser.Camera' is less accessible than method 'Cube_Chaser.DrawableList<T>.DrawableList(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, Cube_Chaser.Camera, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.BasicEffect)"

Comment: Never mind I got it. Had to change the Camera class to a public

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the logical representation of the cube from the physical one. The physical representation would be the vertex buffer etc. This is the same for every cube. You can affect the rendering through e.g. world transforms (as you already did).

The logical representation is your cube class. You will need 100 instances of them (each with their own position, scale etc.). The logical representation can reference the physical one. So there is no need to have more than one vertex buffer.

Comment: So should I change the constructor to include their own position and scale so that in my main class when I call a new cube object I can just set it right then?

Comment: Exactly. Ideally you only create a cube object when you need to (e.g. when initializing). Although it is a light weight class, instantiation takes some time.